# Sanic: Failed to connect Aerospike

Tags: database, python-3.x, kibana, aerospike, sanic

I have problem with connection aerospike. I push docker image to deployment system then I got error when system starting:

```
    ERROR:sanic:Experienced exception while trying to serve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 559, in run
    serve(**server_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 398, in serve
    trigger_events(before_start, loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 352, in trigger_events
    result = event(loop)
  File "/aioads/aioads/sanik.py", line 774, in after_server_stop
    loop.run_until_complete(adserver.init())
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1448, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioads/adserver.py", line 56, in init
    self.lead_collector.init())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioads/storage/aerospike.py", line 38, in init
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(e, self._init)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioads/storage/aerospike.py", line 27, in _init
    'timeout': self.timeout,
exception.ClientError: (-1, 'Failed to connect', 'src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c', 253, False)
```

I tested all locally and sanic was working. I change also timeout but without result. My question is: How can I debug it what's wrong. I have just to access kibana so I can just watch logs. In addition I use supervisor to run it

Comment: Are you able to docker exec into the aerospike container? And check service is running by running asadm -e info

Comment: What's the network layout between your Sanic webserver, Aerospike server, and how is Docker related to any of this?

Comment: Problem was in the file config which is overwrite.